# Xcode 5 update, why am I stuck on Xcode 3.2.6?

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode, macos, software-update

I'm running Xcode (downloaded from the Mac App Store) on my MacBook Pro running OS X Mavericks.

The weird thing is I am running version 3.2.6, yet Xcode claims to be up to date. There are no updates in the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have Xcode 3.2.6 from an earlier installation and are running it. Note that Xcode 3.x being a pre-MAS (Mac App Store) version, installs into the `/Developer` folder (*by default*, although it can be installed elsewhere too), whereas the Mac App Store versions (from Xcode 4 onwards) install into the `/Applications` folder. To run Xcode 5, make sure you're running the application from `/Applications`. You can also use Spotlight to find where Xcode 3.2.6 resides on your system.

If you wish to uninstall the older version (Xcode 3.2.6), open `Terminal.app` and uninstall it using the command:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: It's possible to install Xcode 3 in folders other than  /Developer, although that is the default. Spotlight should be able to help you find any instances of Xcode if it isn't in the /Developer folder.

Comment: Yep it was the dual instillations that was causing a problem with my app launcher. Dumb Dumb. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 was a separate download in the Mac App store. Xcode 5 replaced 4 in the app store. That is why you do not see an update. Download Xcode 5 directly from the Mac Appstore. If you would like to keep xcode 3.2 also installed, right click an xproj file and select to open all these files with xcode 5 to make it the default xcode in your system. But there is no reason nowadays to keep such an old xcode installation.

Answer (score 0):

One very good reason in my book would be the interface - not an MDI-like monolithic structure copied from MSVC, but one with a nice, small project window and source files opening in individual windows. It isn't impossible to add configuration files so that Xcode 3 works with the newer compilers, and if you're using external build systems there shouldn't be any issues at all.

Do I understand correctly that an XCode 3 install isn't touched when upgrading from 10.6 to 10.9?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.